# Laravel Multiauth :Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-5.6

I am trying to implement Laravel multi-authentication in my project.
I followed steps in this link:
https://medium.com/@shuvosutradhar/laravel-5-6-multi-auth-d6641dd2d6e2

When I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:php159
```

Comment: You should make sure you have a valid `return` in the Controller where the issue occurs, that returns either a `view` or an `Response` object. The error indicates that no such `Response` to access/add `headers` on was returned.

Comment: yes thats right , thats no response, I tried dd($response) and it returns null, any idea whats going on?

Comment: Either your Controller never returned a valid one, or some other (custom) middleware returned `null` instead of passing it on.